# How do I resolve NHibernate.MappingException

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

[image]
I have a database, hbm mapping file and the App.config located in a **class library**. Now from a test project I reference that library and attempt to call a HibernateHelper class I create, at runtime the following error is thrown :

**NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: HibernateExample.Mappings.Products.hbm.xml**

Please keep in mind that this is a class library that is being reference from a Test project.
If I change it output type to console application, it runs fine. But when I change it back to class library and reference it from my Test Project it throws the above mention error.

I tried adding config.Configure() but that throws a  NhibernateDuplicateMapping exception.

**FIXED:
Fixed the duplication mapping issue by removing  from appconfig. and fixed the problem mapping entity by placing a hibernate.cfg.xml file in my Test project as well.**

---

```
 public sealed class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    const string Connectionstring = "servicestring";

    public static void OpenSession()
    {      
        var config = new Configuration();                        
        config.Configure();
        config.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());    
        _sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();

    }

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        ISession session = null; 
        if (_sessionFactory == null)
            OpenSession();

        if (_sessionFactory != null)
        {
            session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        return session;
    }

    public static void CloseSessionFactory()
    {
        if (_sessionFactory != null)
        {
            _sessionFactory.Close();
        }
    }


    // var dsn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Connectionstring].ConnectionString;
    //config.SessionFactory().Integrate.Using<MsSqlCeDialect>().Connected.ByAppConfing(dsn);
    // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("My connection string: "+dsn);
    //Get NHibernate configuration 
    //_sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();  
    //config.AddAssembly("HibernateExample");
}
```

Any ideas?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.driver_class"> NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=FirstSample.sdf;</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <mapping assembly="HibernateExample"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>


  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="testconnectionstring"
            connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\FirstSample.sdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
    </connectionStrings>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urnchemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845DCD8080CC91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.242.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

---

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="HibernateExample" namespace="HibernateExample.Domain" >
  <class name="Product" table="Products">
    <id name="Id" type="integer">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" type="string"/>
    <property name="Category" type="string"/>
    <property name="Discontinued" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

Exception Thrown:

```
    Test 'NunitTest.TestClass.canquerydb' failed: NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: HibernateExample.Mappings.Products.hbm.xml
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Could not find the dialect in the configuration
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(String assemblyName)
    NHibernateTest\NHibernateHelper.cs(21,0): at HibernateExample.NHibernateTest.NHibernateHelper.openSession()
    NHibernateTest\NHibernateHelper.cs(28,0): at HibernateExample.NHibernateTest.NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession()
    TestClass.cs(21,0): at NunitTest.TestClass.canquerydb()
    --InvalidOperationException
    at NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.GetDialect(IDictionary`2 props)
    at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName)
```

Comment: Can you post the products.hbm.xml file as well?

Comment: From initial glance it looks ok, check the namespace is correct and check that the Product class is in same namespace.

Comment: @Rippo, yes it is an embedded resource

Comment: @Rippo, I double checked the name space and everything seems to be in order. The fact the entity, the mapping and the app.config are in a dll (class library) shouldn't be an issue should it?

Comment: yes you need something like `<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Domain.Model.Entities" assembly="Domain.Model">`
        `<class name="Domain.Model.Entities.BobClub, Domain.Model" table="clubs">`

Comment: Where Domain.model is my DLL assembly

Comment: @Rippo, I will give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: @Rippo can you take a look at the pic above and let me know if my hbm file reflects the correct setup?

Comment: Is there any InnerExceptions?

Comment: When asking about an error, always post `exception.ToString()`, not just the message.

Comment: @MehmetAtaş . Exception posted in Edit.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon Exception has been posted in edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it appears that you are not configuring the `Dialect` before adding the mapping. This is required.

Here's a simple piece of basic configuration code:

```
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.SessionFactory().Integrate.Using<MsSql2012Dialect>()
                                        .Connected.ByAppConfing("connName");//sic
//now you can add the mappings
```

Comment: Doesn't the property declaration : <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect</property> take care of that?

Comment: If you'd like to stick to XML configuration (I don't, hence the sample code) you still need to call `configuration.Configure()`

Comment: when I call configuration.Configure() it gives me a NHibernate.DuplicateMappingException exception.

Comment: It would be nice to hear the solution.  I'm having the same problem.